# How to supply a class-path to an external JAR through Java Web Start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm making a small interface for a console app, and as such I'm executing the console app and then running commands through the command line.

My issue is that the JAR that I'm executing needs to be supplied a path to a JAR library. However I have no idea how to correctly pass this information. According to the information I found in [*JNLP File Syntax*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html), I should add all external JARs to the JAR path in my JNLP file.

This file looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar href="uToolGUI.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="uTool.jar"/>
    <jar href="jpcap.jar"/>
</resources>
```

The line I'm currently executing is this:

```
java.exe -cp lib\jpcap.jar;. -jar D:\jarCreateLib\uTool.jar gen
```

So I guess the question boils down to - how do I refer to my wanted library in a way such that Web Start will allow me to do so.

This works like a charm when executed through Eclipse. If I have to run it through `java -jar...`, I have to add in `-Djnlp.java.library.path=lib` however this makes no difference whenever I try to execute it thorugh Java Web Start.

Thanks in advance for any and all replies and answers.

Comment: What does the `manifest` say?

Comment: There's this line other than the standart ones and signing of the files


Main-Class: uTool.View.MainViewFrame

Answer (score 2):

The command [`java -jar …`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) uses the `Class-Path` found in the manifest, not the path(s) specified in the `-cp` option. As suggested [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), you need a manifest entry such as this:

```
Class-Path: lib/uToolGUI.jar lib/uTool.jar lib/jpcap.jar
```

As noted in [*JNLP File Syntax*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html), the `main-class` attribute in the JNLP file can be omitted if the first JAR file specified in the JNLP file can be found from the `Main-Class` manifest entry in the JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

The JNLP snippet assumes the Jars are in the same (unnamed) directory - the code-base, while the command line invocation points to one in the `lib` directory, & the other in `jarCreateLib`.

I strongly suggest you check the JNLP with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  One of the things it checks is that the resources declared in the JNLP are available relative to the code-base specified.

Comment: +1 The path disparities are probably critical. Would it be appropriate to specify the ancillary JARs as either <resources> or `Class-Path` entries in the manifest?

Comment: @trashgod Yes.  `Class-Path` is newer (1.5 for applets & JWS AFAIR), but both work from then on.  JaNeLA uses only the JNLP information, so will miss all the Jars specified in the manifest.  OTOH declaring the Jars in the `resources` section has advantages - download can be controlled for eager/lazy, parts specification, the ability to separate archives into extensions  etc.

Comment: @AndrewThompson this will not help if I want to load local jar in client machine of Java WS application user , right?

Comment: @swapnil7 A **lot** changes in over 6 years! JWS itself is about to be deprecated.